# Confusion on Spring Boot Dependency Injection about `Dynamic Injection`

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

There is two Bean MyProperities and MyTask:

```
@Component
class MyTask(@Qualifier("p1") val b: MyProperties)

class MyProperties

@Configuration
open class MyPropertiesConfig {

    @Bean("p1")
    open fun get1() = MyProperties()

    @Bean("p2")
    open fun get2() = MyProperties()
}
```

MyProperties is the properties from application.properties(or other properties file) holder class. The number of MyProperties is `n`, and MyTask will do different tasks according to MyProperties content. It there any graceful way that I can dynamic inject the bean MyProperties(which have different content), so that MyTask can do something according MyProperties?

I have an method, but it is so ugly like this...

```
@Configuration
open class MyTaskConfig {

    @Bean("t1")
    open fun getT1(@Qualifier("p1") @Autowired p: MyProperties) = MyTask(p)

    @Bean("t2")
    open fun getT2(@Qualifier("p2") @Autowired p: MyProperties) = MyTask(p)
}

class MyTask(val p: MyProperties)

@Configuration
open class MyPropertiesConfig {

    @Bean("p1")
    open fun get1() = MyProperties()

    @Bean("p2")
    open fun get2() = MyProperties()
}

class MyProperties

@Component
class TestClass {

    @Qualifier("t1")
    @Autowired
    lateinit var task1: MyTask

    @Qualifier("a2")
    @Autowired
    lateinit var task2: MyTask
}
```

Thanks for your watching and answers!

Comment: Don't tag java if it's not java

Comment: How do you want to choose between dependencies? You can do it thought proxy anyway. For example when you inject request scope bean into a singleton bean. 
But you must define your own scope to do it, and implement your bean selecting mechanism. Then use @Scope annotation with the proper scope and proxy settings.

Comment: @zlaval Thanks for your replying! I'm a newer on Spring World. you mentioned the annotation Scope, I have google it, I afraid it can work for my expect. I want to "dynamic inject" beans. I have edited my question, maybe this time the description is more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: As I understand you dont want a bean with dynamic injection, but you want to create n number of MyTask bean instances with different properties, where n is the number of the configurations comes from app props or something like this (so, dynamic bean creation). How do you define the properties in prop file, its a stucture or a single line? After you read your properties, you can use BeanDefinitionRegistry, looping throught the props and create the beans (use BeanFactoryPostProcessor to postprocess the bean factory)